# Python - if argument is empty

Tags: python

I have some logic that is doing some checking and a calculation using the same character in two dictionaries and appending a `maximum` character to a result_list depending on the result of the calculation.

```
do = dict(dict_b)
output = {::::logic to figure out which key/values to use for maximum::::}

maximum = max(output, key=output.get)
    final_list.append(maximum)
```

When there are no more characters for maximum, I get a `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence` error, which is somewhat expected.

When this happens, i'd like to take a character from a alternate_list and append that to final_list instead.

How do I add a check to see if max() is an empty sequence and do something else (append from alternate_list) instead?

Thanks.

Comment: put it within `try`/`catch` blocks, so when the `ValueError` exception happens you do the "When this happens," part?

Comment: Can't you just use an `if`, and only call `max` if the `output` isn't empty, then append in the `else`? This may violate Python's "forgivness over permission" philosophy, but constantly catching exceptions in parts you know will fail probably isn't great either.

Comment: These would be `try/except` blocks in python.

Comment: Thanks, that got me moving forward again.

Comment: If you're repeatedly finding the maximum and removing the value you find (instead of only doing it once, as you show in your example code), you probably want to use `sorted` instead (it will be much faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `try/except` block as others (@JacobIRR, @downshift) have noted, should do the trick.

```
do = dict(dict_b)
output = {::::logic to figure out which key/values to use for maximum::::}

try:
    maximum = max(output, key=output.get)
    final_list.append(maximum)
except ValueError:
    final_list.append(ALTERNATEVALUE)
```